Image to text processing is blocking UI
I'm trying to extract text from an image. So, I use google_mlkit_text_recognition and camera API.
The problem is for some low-end devices the UI is not responding properly and seems laggy which isn't a good user experience. I can't use a separate Isolate to recognize the text as  google_mlkit_text_recognition must be run on the main isolate.
So I'm doing the work in an async function but still, the UI is lagging in low-end models with high-resolution camera configuration.
If I set the resolution to .medium, it works fine but the MLKit detection performance is bad. I am seeking some ideas to fine-tune this one.
I am sharing my code below.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_text_recognition/google_mlkit_text_recognition.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:smartdevice/ui/scan_serial_number/serial_number_validator.dart';

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(String)? onCapture;
  CameraView({super.key, this.onCapture});

  @override
  State<CameraView> createState() => _CameraViewState();
}

// Add the WidgetsBindingObserver mixin
class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool _isPermissionGranted = false;
  final _textRecognizer = TextRecognizer();
  bool _isProcessingImage = false;
  late final Future<void> _future;
  var result = '';
  Timer? _timer;

  // Add this controller to be able to control de camera
  CameraController? _cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    _future = _requestCameraPermission();
  }

  // We should stop the camera once this widget is disposed
  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    _stopCamera();
    _timer?.cancel();
    _textRecognizer.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Starts and stops the camera according to the lifecycle of the app
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (_cameraController == null || !_cameraController!.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      _stopCamera();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed &&
        _cameraController != null &&
        _cameraController!.value.isInitialized) {
      _startCamera();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            // Show the camera feed behind everything
            if (_isPermissionGranted)
              FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(
                future: availableCameras(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    _initCameraController(snapshot.data!);
                    if (_cameraController != null) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: screenSize.width,
                        height: screenSize.height,
                        child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  } else {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _requestCameraPermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.camera.request();
    _isPermissionGranted = status == PermissionStatus.granted;
  }

  void _initCameraController(List<CameraDescription> cameras) {
    if (_cameraController != null) {
      return;
    }
    // Select the first rear camera.
    CameraDescription? camera;
    for (var i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      final CameraDescription current = cameras[i];
      if (current.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back) {
        camera = current;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (camera != null) {
      _cameraSelected(camera);
    }
  }

  void _startCamera() {
    if (_cameraController != null) {
      _cameraSelected(_cameraController!.description);
    }
  }

  void _stopCamera() {
    if (_cameraController != null) {
      _cameraController?.dispose();
    }
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  Future<void> _listenToCameraStream() async {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
      if (_cameraController != null && !_isProcessingImage) {
        await _scanImage();
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _cameraSelected(CameraDescription camera) async {
    _cameraController = CameraController(
      camera,
      ResolutionPreset.max,
      enableAudio: false,
      fps: 30,
    );

    await _cameraController!.initialize();

    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {});
    _listenToCameraStream();
  }

  Future<void> _scanImage() async {
    if (_cameraController == null) return;
    _isProcessingImage = true;
    print('## Processing started.');

    try {
      final pictureFile = await _cameraController!.takePicture();

      final file = File(pictureFile.path);

      final inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(file);
      final recognizedText = await _textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);

      List<String> texts = recognizedText.text.split('\n');

      for (final text in texts) {
        print('## $text');
        if (text.isValidSerialNumber) {
          print('## Found valid serial number $text');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('## Error taking photos - ${e.toString()}');
    }
    print('## Processing ended.');
    _isProcessingImage = false;
  }
}

publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.5.0

environment:
  sdk: 3.5.3

dependencies:
  bloc: 8.1.4
  equatable: 2.0.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: 8.1.6
  go_router: 14.2.0
  domain:
    path: domain
  data:
    path: data
  get_it: 7.7.0
  injectable: 2.4.2
  cached_network_image: 3.3.1
  lottie: 3.1.2
  flutter_markdown: 0.7.3
  url_launcher: 6.3.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.19.0
  youtube_player_iframe: 5.1.3
  device_info_plus: 9.1.2
  camera: 0.11.0
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  google_mlkit_text_recognition: ^0.13.1
  image: ^4.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  test: 1.25.7 # workaround to have the dependency in the sub packages
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: 4.0.0
  mocktail: 1.0.4
  injectable_generator: 2.6.1
  # Tool for generating type-safe routes with go_router
  go_router_builder: 2.7.1
  build_runner: 2.4.11
  melos: 6.1.0
  bloc_test: 9.1.7


  module:
    androidX: true
    androidPackage: com.liebherr.hau.smartdevice
    iosBundleIdentifier: com.liebherr.hau.smartdevice




yeah don't run that in any event handler or in any other way that uses the UI thread. spawn a worker thread for this.

Flutter's Isolate or compute can't be used here due to google_mlkit's limitation. If you have any alternative, please provide me some sample code

For those with similar issues: google_mlkit_text_recognition uses MethodChannel to call the native API of Android and iOS in the background to do the image processing. In that case, we can't use the flutter Isolate, compute, method to run this image processing or any other plugin which depends on the main isolate directly. It will throw you a 'Bad state error when you try to execute textRecognizer.processImage() method in a different isolate.
However, code in a spawned isolate will generally not be able to interact with Flutter plugins. This is due to the tight integration between the platform plugin scaffolding and the main application isolate.

Solution: You can use the following Flutter package flutter_isolate. They somehow handled the issue. In that case, you can communicate with similar flutter plug which has issue running in the background.
